# Android custom seekbar not showing before first touch

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I tried to make custom seekbar through xml. But only thumb is shown before first touch. After touch, custom seekbar is shown.

Here is my xml in mainActivity.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="129dp"
    >
    <!--seek bar-->

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:thumb="@mipmap/survey_bar_ic"
        android:thumbOffset="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    </SeekBar>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="37dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/bubble"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/bubble_img"
            android:background="@mipmap/survey_bubble_green"></ImageView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bubble_txt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            ></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is survey_bar_free.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!--basic background-->
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape android:shape="line">
        <stroke android:width="16dp" android:color="#dcdcdc"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="16dp" android:color="#8ed351"/>
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="16dp" android:color="#8ed351"/>
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

And this is mainActivity.java

```
seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener
{
 if(i>free_range)
            {
                if(i>point_range)
                {
                    int cur = (i-point_range)/2+point_num;
                    bubbleText.setText(Integer.toString(cur));
                    seekBar.setProgressDrawable(
                    getDrawable(R.drawable.survey_bar_premium));
            int temp = i/2;
            seekBar.setProgress(temp*2);
            //seekBar.setProgress(cur*2);
            bubbleImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.survey_bubble_blue);
        }
        else
        {
            int cur = i/6;
            bubbleText.setText(Integer.toString(cur));
            seekBar.setProgressDrawable(
                    getDrawable(R.drawable.survey_bar_point));
            seekBar.setProgress(cur*6);
            bubbleImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.survey_bubble_skyblue);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int cur = i/6;
        if(cur==0)
        {
            cur=1;
        }
        bubbleText.setText(Integer.toString(cur));
        seekBar.setProgressDrawable(
                getDrawable(R.drawable.survey_bar_free));
        seekBar.setProgress(cur*6);
        bubbleImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.survey_bubble_green);
    }
 });
 seekBar.setMax(seekBarMax);
 seekBar.setProgress(6);
 seekBar.setProgressDrawable(
            getDrawable(R.drawable.survey_bar_free));
```

Comment: Add android:progressDrawable="@drawable/survey_bar_free" to your Seekbar in xml.

Comment: I tried but still same problem